# Python / Django : Associative arrays error

Tags: python, django, django-views

How do i create an associative array in django? i am new to python

models is a queryset

```
models = Models.objects.filter(year = 1999)
```

Essenstially i am looking to create something that has values:

```
for model in models:
    newarray = {'item1' :model.item1 , 'item2' : model.item2}
```

it doesnt seem to work

i cant access newarray[0] or newarray[1] etc. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hm, I would suggest you to learn basic Python first, for your case everything about basic types, classes and class instances at least, Also you should work on the names if your classes. For example don't name you model `Models`, don't name you instances of the model `models` and so on. Choose names according to what your model is for. For example if your model represent a book collection name it `Book`, therefore the query you are performing could be saved in the `books` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python's dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are pure associative arrays; they cannot be accessed by numerical index. Use `newarray['item1']` or `newarray['item2']` instead.